# Using two contexts in one Transaction and error with DTC

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions, msdtc

In one transation I use two different contexts:

```
 using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
 {

   using (Entities1 context = new Entities1())
   {
    ....
   }

   using (Entities2 context2 = new Entities2())
   {
    .... var tmp = from a in context2....
   }
}
```

When I read context2 I have error:

> Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool

My firewall is turned off. My Components Services: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/109/88086476.png/. But Error still exists! 
How can I fix it ???

Server: Windows Server 2008, MS SQL 2008
Client: Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Have you checked if the `Distributed Transaction Coordinator` in your services has been Started?

Comment: Yes, I have. Distributed Transaction Coordinator is check

Comment: have you read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731495.aspx), to allow network DTC ?

Comment: Yes, I have but nothing works

Comment: Do the contexts have different connection strings?

Comment: Yes, the context have different connectionstrings